# What does ip address | sed -ne 's/^\s*inet \([0-9]\+\).*$/IP:\1/p' mean?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sed, ip

On Ubuntu 14.04 I'm trying to get only the IP address of my computer in a `.csv` format.

Comment: Are you looking for a one-liner, or would a multiline shell script be ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `sed` command may be what you're trying to do

```
ip address |
sed -n -e '/^[[:blank:]]*inet[[:blank:]]/{s///; s/\/.*//; H;}' \
       -e '${g; s/./"/; s/\n/","/g; s/$/"/p;}'
```

Comment: Note that semicolons are not required after `{` or before `}` in a `{ ... }` command group.

Comment: @JohnBollinger The semicolon after `{` is unnecessary indeed. But, it seems the semicolon (or a newline) before `}` is required by POSIX: _The <right-brace> shall be preceded by a <newline> or <semicolon> (before any optional <blank> characters preceding the <right-brace>)._ (quoted from [sed](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html))

Comment: Fair enough.  The trailing semicolon is not required by GNU sed, at least, but I'm all for writing portable code.

Comment: Perfect andswer ! thanks a lot !